# What does Crystal's shield not protect against?

Tags: nuclear-throne

Crystal's active ability allows her to create a shield to protect herself from most enemy attacks, but not all. Assassin's are able to attack through the shield, and the shield doesn't protect against explosions either. What enemies/attacks are able to ignore Crystal's special?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Along with melee attacks and explosions, the following will bypass the shield:

- lasers fired by Laser Crystals (in the Cave level)
- contact damage (enemies like rats or the crystal spiders running through you)

It also doesn't protect from the IDPD Inspector's telekinesis, meaning you can get dragged out of your own shield and damaged.

A longer list of everything the shield reflects/negates/doesn't work against is available [here.](http://nuclear-throne.wikia.com/wiki/Crystal)